# FTP Task: Unable to send files using "FTP Connection Manager" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ftp, ssis-2012

I inconsistently get the following error when uploading files to a ftp server:

> FTP Task: Unable to send files using "FTP Connection Manager"

The port is 21 and it is set to passive mode.  The task succeeds 80% of the time it is executed; the occasional failures are random and I'm looking for the best way to troubleshoot the problem.

Is there any way to get more descriptive error information via visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have resolved it by now. But for the future reference, I'll answer it anyway. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84024/unable-to-connect-to-ftp-server-using-ftp-connection-manager) is the duplicate solution (but I would be careful not to set `UsePassiveMode = False`. Set this to true).

Another mistake I usually make is I forget to choose "override the file if it already exists in the destination", but of course that depends on the requirement as well.